# Iterate over a mongoDB collection, perform an asynchronous task of Aggregation for each item, and when they’re all done return JSON in Response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, async.js

Trying to aggregate some data from a list of MongoDB collection and when aggregation is done over all the collections, I want to return the complete aggregation of all the suitable collections with the name and aggregated value as a JSON object back.
New to node.js programming, hence not able to solve this trivial problem. any help appreciated

Code:

```
app.get('/tester', (req, res) => {

    var AggArr = [];

    db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collInfos) {
        async.forEachOf(collInfos, (value, key, callback) => {
            aggregate(value);
        }, err => {
            if (err)
                console.error(err.message);
            // configs is now a map of JSON data
            res.send(JSON.stringify(AggArr));
        });
    });
        function aggregate(collname) {
        if (collname.name.includes("_tps")) {
            db.collection(collname.name).aggregate([{
                        $match: {
                            $and: [{
                                    TIME: {
                                        $gte: new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z")
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    TIME: {
                                        $lte: new Date("2017-12-31T23:59:59Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        $group: {
                            _id: collname.name,
                            sum: {
                                $sum: "$TPS"

                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]).toArray(
                (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                } else {
                    if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {}
                    else {
                        console.log(result[0]);
                        AggArr.push(result[0]);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        }
    })
```

I'm new to Node.js programming and stuck at this trivial problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: So... how is this not working? Are you getting any result back? Is it not the right format? The right data? What's wrong? You're just saying "I'm trying to aggregate data" but you're not saying what's failing

Comment: No error the page keeps loading

Comment: Have you stepped through the node code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above workflow can be refactored to the following

```
const pipeline = collectionName => (
    [
        { '$match': {
            'TIME': {
                '$gte': new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"), 
                '$lte': new Date("2017-12-31T23:59:59Z")
            }
        } }, 
        { '$group': {
            '_id': collectionName,
            'sum': { '$sum': "$TPS" }
        } }
    ]
);

db.listCollections().toArray((err, collInfos) => {
    const agg = collInfos
        .filter(col => col.name.includes("_tps"))
        .map(col => db.collection(col.name).aggregate(pipeline(col.name)).toArray());

    Promise.all(agg).then(data => {
        const results = data.map(d => d[0]);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return a response of any query it should be like below. It will gives response in `JSON` format.

```
    app.get('/tester', (req, res) => {
    //DB Operaations
    if (success) {
        res.status(200).json(success);
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Something went wrong'
        });
    }
});
```